# Preventing videos in carousel from all playing at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, bootstrap-4, carousel

EDIT: I'm now using rows and columns of videos for my site instead (just easier!) but if anyone knows the answer to this question I'm still curious :)

I've been learning about designing websites with Bootstrap and I have a carousel that plays some hard-coded videos. It works for the most part except for the fact that they all play at the same time and I'm not sure how to get them to stop doing that. I'd like for each video to play automatically, but only if the user is looking at the slide containing that respective video (obviously). I've really only started learning Bootstrap and JavaScript this past week so which I think is why I'm having trouble implementing solutions... for example I tried to add code to my .js file and it seemed render the "previous" and "next" buttons inoperable. Any advice? Here's my code for the carousel:

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
              </ol>
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="videos/vid1.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="videos/vid2.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="videos/vid3.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="videos/vid4.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="videos/vid5.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `data-interval="false"`

```
<div id="your-carousel-id" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
    .....
</div>
```

Comment: I hadn't tried that! Hmm, it doesn't appear to be working for me though. Thank you anyway!